# Getting indexPath of tableView inside tableViewCell file during cell creation/dequeueing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am creating a scrollable view filled with monthly calendars. I'm using a collection view to display a calendar inside a table view full of calendars. So each table view cell is a calendar for a specific month, and each collection view cell is a day. I have a separate swift file for the tableview cell from the view controller. Since each tableview cell is going to look different (because different months), the tableview cell needs to know which row it is placed in inside the tableview during its creation in dequeque cell function.

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CalendarTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
```

I need to get the indexPath in the "for: indexPath" parameter inside the tableview cell file because the collectionview inside the tableview cell gets created when the tableview cell is dequeued. The contents of the collection view depends on which tableview row it's in. So how do I get that parameter?

Sorry for the long explanation, please help if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Why does the cell need to know which row it is in?  It might need to know what month or year it is for, but even then you could instantiate a collection view data source object and pass that to the cell

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but if you need to do that you probably have a flaw in your app architecture

Comment: Hm..is it possible to pass data to the cell before it starts creating stuff in the cell like the collection view? I wasn't totally sure what you meant in your first comment but I need the row because first row is current month's calendar, second is the calendar from the past month, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in UITableViewCell subclass and use that array in collection view data source methods.

```
class MonthCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let datesArray = [String]()
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datesArray.count
    }
}
```

In `tableView cellForRowAt` method assign the date values and reload the `collectionView`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! MonthCell
    cell.datesArray = []//dates based on indexPath
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

---

Or

Assign a reference to the table view cell index path in `tableView cellForRowAt` method

```
class MonthCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    var tableIndexPath:IndexPath?
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let tableIndexPath {
            // return value based on tableIndexPath
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

//cellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MonthCell") as! MonthCell
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rajesh! This is what I was looking for, and I think I'll use this solution. I was planning on changing the contents of the collection view in a function somewhere outside the cellForRowAt function after scrolling to every table view so that they'll all be visible cells but I think yours is cleaner.